# Oracle - Using a Sub Query

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I am attempting to write a Select statement that will review items sold to a our customers.  I would like to see all of the customers that made multiple purchases within the same day and the sales numbers associated with them.

**Here is my current structure:**

Table: Sales

Fields: SalesNum, customer, SaleDt

**Test Data**

```
Customer  -  SalesNum  -  SaleDt  
---------------------------------
Mike    -     1        -   1/1/15
Bob     -     2        -   1/1/15
Mike    -     3        -   1/1/15
Tom     -     4        -   1/2/15
Tom     -     5        -   1/2/15
```

**Desired Results**

```
Customer  -  SalesNum  -  SaleDt 
---------------------------------
Mike    -     1        -   1/1/15
Mike    -     3        -   1/1/15
Tom     -     4        -   1/2/15
Tom     -     5        -   1/2/15
```

I appreciate any insight and advice as to a method to use.

Comment: If you need to get the desired result you can run the below query and check.      sql query to get exact desired results in your question                                   select * from  Sales where customer in ('Mike','Tom')  order by  customer asc

Answer (score 0):

doesn't seems to be clear enough, I would say that

Select Customer, SalesNum, SaleDt from Sales where SaleDt = sysdate order by Customer;

that will list the today's sales ordered by customers according to your explanation this is the result but is it ?

Comment: BTW ? why to use a SubQuery  please clarify

Comment: Unfortunately I don't just want today's sales.  I need it over a period of time.

Comment: I thought I would need to use a subquery based on research I have done.  I essentially need information that has a match on SalesDT.  In my example of a desired return, I show just the sales where SalesDT matched for a single customer but they had different SalesNum.

Comment: mmm like this ?   Select Customer, SalesNum, SaleDt from Sales where between to_date('01/01/2015' ,'dd-mm-rrrr') and to_date('01/02/2015','dd-mm-rrrr') order by Customer;

Comment: oh you need only the customers that made more than one purchase, I see But  in a range of time ?

Comment: Aramillo answers prolly will help you with, BTW what you need is called a self join

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data:

```
with sales (Customer , SalesNum , SaleDt) as (  
select 'Mike' , 1 , '1/1/15' from dual union all
select 'Bob' , 2 , '1/1/15' from dual  union all
select 'Mike' , 3 , '1/1/15' from dual  union all
select 'Tom' , 4 , '1/2/15' from dual  union all
select 'Tom' , 5 , '1/2/15' from dual )

select customer,salesnum,s.saledt,total from sales s inner join (
select saledt,customer,count(*) total from sales
group by saledt,customer) using (customer)
where total>1 and customer = 'Mike'
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMER   SALESNUM SALEDT      TOTAL
-------- ---------- ------ ----------
Mike              1 1/1/15          2
Mike              3 1/1/15          2
```

Or maybe you want salesnums separated by comma, for avoid duplicates like this:

```
select customer,saledt,to_char(wm_concat(salesNum)) salesNums,count(*) total 
from sales
group by saledt,customer
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMER   SALEDT   SALESNUMS   TOTAL
Bob        1/1/15       2         1
Mike       1/1/15      1,3        2
Tom        1/2/15      4,5        2
```

Comment: Aramillo, Thanks for the comment.  I tried to use this but it did not show the desired result.  Instead, I received duplicates of the first entry.

Comment: Can you show which is your expected output?. Second result is identical to the ouput in the question, except by total column.

Comment: Unfortunately when I put it in, I added an and statement to the end stating:
and customer = 'Mike'
My output was the following:
Mike - 1 - 1/1/15 - 2
Mike - 1 - 1/1/15 - 2
Mike - 1 - 1/1/15 - 2

Comment: I really don't understand, check update, where i used your sample data